# OpenSSL gives "iv undefined" for AES-256-ECB

Tags: openssl, aes

Can anyone spot why this command gives "iv undefined"?

```
>openssl.exe enc -d -aes-256-ecb -K 8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 -in ex3.8_C.bin -out plaintext.bin -nopad
iv undefined
```

See also [Basic AES decryption problem](https://superuser.com/questions/957809/basic-aes-decryption-problem)

Answer (score 1):

It is as it says you did not define the `iv`

Try like this: `-iv 0`

```bsh
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -in test.txt -out output.txt -K 1234567812346578 -iv 0 -p
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I was using ECB (not CBC) which I understood does not (and cannot) use an initial vector. (As discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789709/is-it-possible-to-use-aes-with-an-iv-in-ecb-mode )